# Checker deselect with disconnected faces on same object

Tags: selection-tools

Select random even works on unconnected faces when part of the same object.
Why checker deselect doesn't work that way?

Comment: Hello :). Well, that's just how it works - [Blender Manual - Checker Deselect](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/selecting/checker_deselect.html)

Comment: Just to explain - checker deselect goes in all four directions ← ↑ ↓ →, and simply doesn't know how to continue on disconnected faces :).

Comment: There is no operator (currently) that jumps to disconnected geometry and keeps a pattern, `Ctrl-Shift-Num+` ([select next](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/selecting/more_less.html#select-next-previous-active))is the same way...

Comment: Checker deselect works after randomising vertex indices... it _uses_ edge-connectivity to decide what a 'checker' is. You can stash selections in vertex groups..

Answer (score 3):

Okay, as Jachym Michal pointed out checker deselect only looks in all directions and stops at disconnected geometry. It doesn't jump over to the next elements index of the object when it finds disconnected geometry.

Here is a script that selects every other polygon, assuming their indices are ordered.

```
import bpy
obj = bpy.context.active_object
i=0
for p in obj.data.polygons:
    if i%2:
        p.select = True
    i+=1
```

Comment: .. and you can order vertex-indices in various ways, yourself, using _Mesh > Sort Elements_